# PTX - get value/address

Tags: cuda, nvidia, ptx

I don't understand how the mov instruction works in PTX..

```
mov.type d, a
```

this moves a in d if a is a register or immediate value. By the way this can move into d the address of a if a is a variable in global, local or shared state space.

Let's suppose that a is a variable in global memory and points to an u64 with value 0x1... how do I store 0x1 into d since I can only get a's address??

I'm not sure on how to get a value instead of an address.. something like intel ASM's mov eax, ebx for address and mov eax, [ebx] for value (dereferencing ebx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042176/load-function-parameters-in-inlined-ptx/16051285#16051285) should help you. It shows a worked example of using the `mov` and `ld`  instructions to load a value from a pointer.

Comment: Thanks Robert, now I get it. It's working in a very similar way to Intel syntax's assembly. This will facilitate me greatly :D