# CUDA/PTX 32-bit vs. 64-bit

Tags: cuda, nvcc, ptx

CUDA compilers have options for producing 32-bit or 64-bit PTX. What is the difference between these? Is it like for x86, NVidia GPUs actually have 32-bit and 64-bit ISAs? Or is it related to host code only?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sixtyfour-bit-compatibility

Comment: +Sagar Masuti: I've seen this, but it's really not helpful to my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointers are certainly [the most obvious difference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#sixtyfour-bit-compatibility).  64 bit machine model enables 64-bit pointers.  64 bit pointers enable a variety of things, such as address spaces larger than 4GB, and [unified virtual addressing](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED).  Unified virtual addressing in turn enables other things, such as [GPUDirect Peer-to-Peer](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__PEER.html#group__CUDART__PEER).  The [CUDA IPC API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE) also depends on 64 bit machine model.

The x64 ISA is not *completely different* than the x86 ISA, it's mostly an extension of it.  Those familiar with the x86 ISA will find the x64 ISA familiar, with natural extensions for 64-bits where needed.  Likewise 64 bit machine model is an extension of the capabilities of the PTX ISA to 64-bits.  Most PTX instructions work exactly the same way.

32 bit machine model can handle 64 bit data types (such as `double` and `long long`), so frequently there don't need to be any changes to properly written CUDA C/C++ source code to compile for 32 bit machine model or 64 bit machine model.   If you program directly in PTX, [you may have to account for the pointer size differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042176/load-function-parameters-in-inlined-ptx/16051285#16051285), at least.

Comment: So are new devices (say Kepler class) all 64-bit? or is there a mix? Given a 64-bit device, why would I want to use it in 32-bit mode? In x86 vs. x64 there's the issue of pointer sizes and hence more memory occupied for some processes. Is this the same issue for Cuda? Or should I just always use 64-bit and forget about it?

Comment: All newer devices support either 32 bit or 64 bit machine model.  Some older devices support only 32 bit model.  In many respects, 64-bit mode is better, for the reasons I gave in my answer.  The only reason I can think of using 32 bit mode is that some codes may run slower in 64 bit mode, e.g. due to 64 bit pointer arithmetic.  Personally I would always just use 64-bit mode and forget about 32 bit mode.  32 bit support is already not available [for some OS's](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux-5-5).  And yes, 64-bit code may compile to a larger size.

Comment: Thank you - exactly the answer I was hoping for.